# Are indirectly inherited methods supposed to be accessed from a class that does not directly realize the containing interfaces

Tags: interface, uml, enterprise-architect, component-diagram

I have the below component diagram where a component's interface SWC1_Interface is decomposed into multiple interfaces (only one shown here) that break down the functionality provided by the main component interface, just to group the APIs into logical groups. Class1 realizes the SWC1_Interface_SubGrouping.

[image: My dummy component diagram and interface analysis/decomposition]

Then I draw a sequence diagram and try to specify a message requested from the instance of Class1. In the dropdown I can see the api1() which is a method of Class1 and is expected there, but I can also see all the indirect inherited methods from the realization sequence in the component diagram.

[image: My dummy sequence diagram]

My questions are:

1. Is my component diagram respecting the UML standard and what could I do to improve it?
2. Does it make sense to "decompose" interfaces like this?
3. Is EA's behaviour, in the way that it shows the indirectly inherited messages as options in the message, "normal" and sensible?
4. Is there a way to change this behaviour in EA, to block indirectly inherited operations from showing up as options for messages in a sequence diagram?

Comment: You use Realization, not Generalization...

Answer (score 3):

**1. Respect of UML**

From the point of vie of the syntax, it looks almost correct.  But unfortunately, it doesn't mean what you think:

- If `SWC1_Interface`  is an interface provided by the component, the notation would either be a lollipop or the interface realization arrow (component at the tail, interface at the head) instead of the association (which means the component is associated with a classifier implementing the interface)
- Very probably,  the interface `SWC1_Interface_subgrouping` should not realise the interface `SWC1_Interface`,  but inherit from it (plain line instead of dashed).
- Even more probably, the decomposition should be in the other direction.  Indeed,  if `SWC1_Interface_subgrouping` would inherit from `SWC1_Interface`, it would have all the features of `SWC1_Interface` and more.  What you want is to say that in fact `SWC1_Interface` realises one or several other interfaces, thus adding up the features of each.

**2. Does it make sense to decompose the interfaces**

It can make sense. For example, you could imagine that a component provides the interface `PrintableAndSortable` that is a combination of two distinct interfaces `Printable` and `Sortable`.

However,  the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) suggests that in many cases, this might not be a good idea, from a design point of view.

**3. Indirectly inherited messages**

It is normal that the public feature of all the indirect parents are also features of the inheriting class:  Suppose A inherits from B which inherits from C.  The inheritance tells us that B is a C and A is a B and therefore also a C.

For the realisation it's less obvious, because the realisation theoretically only says that the class realising the interface should provide on its own the different properties and operations.  However, it's common accepted to assume that the class will comply and therefore consider this properties and operations will also be available.  ,

**EA behaviour**

I don't know, but I don't think so.

Comment: Your "even more probably" case is the correct one. I updated into SWC1---(realizes)--->SWC1_Interface, which in turn, SWC1_Interface---(realizes)--->SWC1_SubInterface1/2/3 to inherit and add up all the sub-features into one central interface. 
The whole point of this exercise is to have one central point of reference for the component's interface for the architectural design and at the same time be able to decompose it into smaller chunks/interfaces to support the detail design, so that each class of the detail design has its own smaller scope interface to realize.

Comment: With this realizations configuration as mentioned in my comment above, the message selection in EA only gives two options one for the direct apiX() operation of the class and another for the equivalent from the SWC1_SubInterfaceX, which is certainly much cleaner.

Comment: I see. It's a kind of [facade](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade) interface at component level where different parts of the interface are to be implemented by different classes. Makes sense. I'd still suggest to have SWC1_Interface---(***inherit***)--->SWC1_SubInterface1/2/3 because composing interfaces, like here, is according to UML semantics more about an interface inheriting a contract than an interface realising it (i.e. implementing). Just to be sure: so you now have the desired EA behavior?

Comment: In reality, I want to have an interface to represent the component's provided functionality at an architecture level and then I want to break this interface down to smaller parts to help with intra-component interactions at a detail design level. It is just semantics and documentation to cover ASPICE at all levels and in parallel assist the detail designers.
No, I still see the inherited interfaces in sequence diagrams. At least now I only have the correct interfaces. It is better but still not perfect.
That's why I haven't yet accepted yours as the answer.